# CDF of continuous distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics

We know CDF of a continuous distribution follows Uniform[0,1]. For an example if X and Y are two Normal random variables with mean 0 and $\mu$ with common standard deviation 1, then standardized CDFs at $-\inf < X < z$ for X is $\Phi(z)$ and at $-\inf < Y < z$ for Y is $\Phi(z-\mu)$, but both CDFs follow Uniform[0,1]. My question is how are they different, or how one would know these two uniforms are different?

Thank you

Comment: Is it true that $\mu$ has a standard deviation of $1$ ? Consequently $\mu$ must be a random variable.

Comment: here $\mu$ is constant, mean parameter of the normal distribution

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question. It is not sufficiently clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ with cdf $\Phi(x)$. We know that $\Phi(x)$ is continuous and increasing; define $Z=\Phi(X)$ and note that $Z$ takes values in $[0,1]$.  We have
$$
F_Z(z)=\mathbb P(Z\le z)=\mathbb P\left(X\le \Phi^{-1}(z)\right)=\Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(z)\right)=z
$$
that is $Z=\Phi(X)\sim\mathcal U([0,1])$.
The same is true for $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,\mu)$, i.e. $W=\Phi(Y-\mu)\sim\mathcal U([0,1])$.

In general, if $X$ is a continuous random variable with cumulative distribution function $F_X$, then the random variable $Y=F_X(X)$ has a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. And the inverse of this: if Y has a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ and if $X$ has a cumulative distribution $F_X$, then the random variable $F_X^{-1}(Y)$ has the same distribution as $X$.